# Как можно соединить uploadify + carrierwave для загрузки аватара?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Можно ли как-то реализовать чтобы после загрузки сразу появилась картинка, чтобы сразу можно было ее редактировать с помощью jcrop

```
var uploadify_script_data = {};
$('#uploadify').uploadify({
    uploader        : '/assets/uploadify.swf',
    script          : '<%=pictures_path%>',
    cancelImg       : '/images/cancel.png',
    auto            : true,
    multi           : true,
    removeCompleted : true,
    scriptData      : uploadify_script_data,
    onComplete      : function(event, ID, fileObj, doc, data){
    }
});
```

Пробую вот этот код но выдает 405

```
def create
      render json: {image_path: image.file_path}
      @restaurant = current_user.restaurants.build(restaurant_params)
      if @restaurant.save
        flash[:success] = 'Поздравляем! Ваше заведение создано!'
        redirect_to restaurant_profile_index_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end


def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:image)
end
```

Comment: Скорее всего да, но вам придётся разобрать совершаемые запросы и написать логику их обработки на сервере. Библиотеки не всегда хорошо стыкуются между собой, так что иногда приходится всё-таки изучать то, на базе чего они сделаны.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не нашёл на [офф. сайте](http://www.uploadify.com/) `uploadify` некоторые использованные опции. Возможно, использована более старая версия.

Но вообще, нас интересует событие [onUploadSuccess](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/).

Должно получиться что-то типа:

```
$('#uploadify').uploadify({
  'swf': '/assets/uploadify.swf',
  'uploader': '<%=pictures_path%>', //собственно, урл куда загружать файл
  'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
    $('#uploaded_container').attr('src', data.image_path)
  }
})
```

Чтобы заработало, нужно:

1. Добавить в html-код страницы тэг `<img id="uploaded_container" src="">`
2. Соответствующим образом обработать изображение на стороне сервера. Например так:

PicturesController:

```
def create
  # код, который валидирует и сохраняет файл
  render json: {image_path: image.file_path}
end
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: не пойму почему но выдает при загрузке 500, и в консоле NameError (undefined local variable or method `image' for ...)

Comment: Возможно, по тому, что в коде экшена `image` используется без инициализации? Да и вообще, судя по коду, это вполне себе `html`'ный экшн, который создаёт рестораны, а не обрабатывает загрузку картинки.

Comment: я вот не пойму, допустим есть большая форма где есть много полей, и есть поля для загрузки фоток, нельзя ли сделать чтобы загружал фотки и они сразу появлялись для дальнейшего изменения, но при этом ты не нажимал в форме "отправить"